# Group events by date

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have this Oracle table which I use for events

```
CREATE TABLE EVENT(
  ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
  SOURCE VARCHAR2(50 ),
  TYPE VARCHAR2(50 ),
  EVENT_DATE DATE,
  DESCRIPTION VARCHAR2(100 )
)
/
```

I use this SQL query to get the data by type:

```
SELECT EVENT_DATE, SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'Error' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ERROR, 
SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'Warning' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS WARN, 
SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'Info' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS INFO, 
SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'Critical' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CRITICAL
FROM EVENT E WHERE EVENT_DATE >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 7 
GROUP BY EVENT_DATE 
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN TYPE IN ('Info', 'Warning', 'Error', 'Critical') THEN 1 END) > 0
ORDER BY EVENT_DATE
```

How I can the result for a day? I want to get all events for 7 days split for every day. I should have 7 rows of data result

Comment: Are you sure that your date does not also have a timestamp?

Comment: Please post some sample data, your current output and the desired output.

Comment: @durbnpoisn - I have timestamp

Comment: @PM77-1 I just want to group the result by date For example for one week I have 7 days. I want to get 7 rows with result

Comment: Can you show me how to modify the query. I have very basic knowledge in Oracle

Comment: @PM77-1 is right. I posted the query in an answer. The trunc-function sets the timestamp on Oracle date to 00:00:00 and that's what you need to GROUP BY date only.

Answer (score 3):

Of course David Bachmann Jeppesen answer is correct, but your query can be simplified.

The HAVING-condition can be applied already in WHERE reducing the number of rows *before* the aggregation:

```
SELECT trunc(EVENT_DATE) event_date,
   SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'Error' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ERROR,
   SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'Warning' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS WARN,
   SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'Info' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS INFO,
   SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'Critical' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CRITICAL
FROM EVENT E
WHERE EVENT_DATE >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 7
  AND TYPE IN ('Info', 'Warning', 'Error', 'Critical')
GROUP BY trunc(EVENT_DATE)
ORDER BY trunc(EVENT_DATE)
```

Comment: Additionally can you show me how I can show the result by hour?

Comment: @PeterPenzov: `TRUNC` has an optional parameter: `TRUNC(EVENT_DATE, 'HH')` truncates to the hour

Comment: One more question. I need to pass trunc(EVENT_DATE) as parameter. Something like trunc(?). Is there any way to pass days and hours as a param?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT trunc(EVENT_DATE) event_date,
SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'Error' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ERROR,
SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'Warning' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS WARN,
SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'Info' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS INFO,
SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'Critical' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CRITICAL
FROM EVENT E
WHERE EVENT_DATE >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 7
GROUP BY trunc(EVENT_DATE)
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE IN ('Info', 'Warning', 'Error', 'Critical') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
ORDER BY trunc(EVENT_DATE)
```